# Slow cheetah Add Transform does not appear

Tags: visual-studio, slowcheetah

I want to use Slow Cheetah for transform .config file. Currently I am using Visual Studio 2017 and for this I have installed Slow Cheetah 2.5.48 from nuget but 'Add Transform' does not appear when I right-click on config file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a work-around you could do this by hand.
Make a copy in the _Solution Explorer* of your Web.config and rename it to *Web.Debug.config* or whatever you like.

Unload the project and then Edit the project.
Find the *ItemGroup* element that contains your newly created config file and add the `<DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>` element there, like so:

[image]

After that, it will look like this in the Solution Explorer:

[image]

Now you can edit your newly added config file with the required transformations.

Comment: Yes that is a solution but I want to do this using Slow Cheetah.

Comment: Yes. It is described here. https://github.com/Microsoft/slow-cheetah/blob/master/doc/transforming_files.md A NuGet package is available for integration with the build.

Comment: Ok but Slow Cheetah is not working on Visual Studio 2017. I also tried your solution which you have mentioned above but it is also not working in VS 2017.

Comment: Did you read the Getting Started section on the link I posted earlier? The extension that is mentioned is for VS2015-2017. That will add the **Add transform** context menu item and also a **Preview transform**. You'll need the NuGet package that is specified to have your config transformed during the build.

Comment: Yes I have installed extension as well as nuget package already.

Comment: And you don't see those extra context menu options when right clicking an `App.config`?

Comment: Yes I don't see

Answer (score 37):

The issue is, only adding nugget would not suffice. You need to install slowcheetah from visual studio marketplace. Following are the steps:

1. Install SlowCheetah from Tools > Extensions and Updates
2. Restart VS, allowing for the VSIX installer to run
3. Create new C# App (.NET Framework). (In my case, it started to work on existing app also.)

**[GitHub Reference](https://github.com/Microsoft/slow-cheetah/issues/74)**

Comment: For people looking at this with latest VS 2019 updates, Extensions can now be found next to the 'Tools' button as its own separate section.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I installed the NuGet package 2.5.48 and then was able to download and install the vsix file from here and it worked:

https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/releases

Answer (score 2):

1. Download it here
   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WillBuikMSFT.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms or search for "SlowCheetah" in Visualstudio marketplace,
2. install it
3. restart you VS and see.
   Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Correct as @Himanshu Singla and many others here are saying, in addition to installing **nuget package**, you still need to download the Extension from **Tools**->**Extensions and Updates**-> Search **"Slow Cheetah"**, install and restart VS.

Comment: Looks like a comment

Comment: Apologies, still cant comment to the above solutions, as I am still building up my reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following before it worked:

1. Install the package from their site instead of from NuGet
2. List item

Restart VS

Then the Add Transform option started showing up in the drop-down menu.